# Is Prisma ORM stack good for new webapp (Nextjs + Nodejs)

Tags: node.js, orm, prisma

I know the title is silly but I'm in real confusion now. Let's me explain the details:

I'm going to build a new webapp using NextJS (basically React) and I want my backend to use GraphQL. When searching for some additional technologies, I found `Prisma` but don't understand it correctly even reading the whole docs & website.

1. In the traditional app, we have **Frontend** → **Backend** → **Database**, they're 3 important parts of a webapp
2. I can use `Nextjs` in *FE*, `Nodejs` to build `GraphQL APIs` in *BE*, using `MongoDB` or `PostgresQL` as *DB*
3. Now we have `Prisma`. When searching for some expamles, I have something growing in my mind:
   3.1 So `Prisma` is like a version of LinQ in Nodejs app?
   3.2 `NextJS` (FE) can use `Prisma` to query data from *DB* → **Where is the BE part? Is Prisma considered BE?**
   3.3 Talk about scalability, if I want to build a new mobile app that sync with the webapp, I will not have the *Backend* to reuse and have to implement the whole stuff from the scratch: something like `React Native` + `Prisma`, correct?
   3.4 I also found some other examples showing that we can use `Prisma` in Nodejs app (BE) to build APIs. **Why do we need `Prisma` when `Nodejs` + `MongoDB` is enough?**

I'm so confused about them so I hope the questions are clear.

Answer (score 6):

ORM is an object-relational mapper. Meaning you don't have to write certain Database queries from scratch

Example raw mongodb query

```
db.mycol.findOne({title: "MongoDB Overview"})
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dd6542170fb13eec3963bf0"),
    "title" : "MongoDB Overview",
    "description" : "MongoDB is no SQL database",
    "by" : "tutorials point",
    "url" : "http://www.tutorialspoint.com",
    "tags" : [
        "mongodb",
        "database",
        "NoSQL"
    ],
    "likes" : 100
}
```

using an ORM like Mongoosejs or Prisma

Mongoosejs

```
let character = await Character.findOne({ name: 'Frodo' })
```

Prisma

```
const allPosts: Post[] = await prisma.post.findMany()
```

ORM makes your life easier. If you like to write raw queries, go ahead :)

List of ORMs that you can choose from

1. https://typeorm.io/#/
2. https://mongoosejs.com/
3. https://www.prisma.io/
4. https://sequelize.org/

For me, I would personally go with Prisma or Mongoose

1. You can call Prisma from Next.js but it's better to call it from
   your node.js API. If it's a small project yeah go ahead and use
   Next.js and Prisma
2. You can use react-native and node.js as your backend. For ORM of
   course you can choose any of the ORMs above
3. When it comes to scalability, I don't think you should think about
   this first, which is more towards your Infrastructure like AWS. I
   recommend you to use Vercel for Next.js and Heroku for your Node.js
   api
4. You can use RDS from AWS to spin up your PostgreSQL or MySQL
5. You can spin up a mongodb database from mongodb atlas

Answer (score 2):

Prisma is a Database Toolkit so that's definitely a part of the **Backend**.

The Database Toolkit involves **Prisma ORM** (Basically you won't have to write RAW SQL Queries in your GraphQL API to fetch data from your database, Prisma will do it for you). You will write your Prisma Queries in your GraphQL queries to fetch data and mutations to create data.

**Next.js** blurs the lines between client and server. You can use Prisma in the front end with Next.js in `getStaticProps()`, `getServerSideProps()` and `API Routes` but in your case, this won't be scalable as the mobile app cannot use these methods. Instead, a stand-alone server will be preferable and your GraphQL APIs can be consumed by both the Next.js Web App as well as React Native mobile app.

By using Prisma along with Node.js and MongoDB would make building app faster as Prisma exposes CRUD and other aggregation operations using [PrismaClient](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#prismaclient) based on your models.

This official example of using [Prisma with GraphQL and Next.js](https://github.com/prisma/prisma-examples/tree/latest/typescript/graphql-nextjs) should be helpful.

Comment: A mobile app would be able to call the API routes created via Next.js, right?

Answer (score -2):

I do not believe Mongoose is an ORM, it's an ODM. MongoDB is intrinsically non-relational, it's a Document Database. I suppose including Mongoose isn't that criminal in the list of ORM's, but really I think the differentiation is still important.